# ESP32 Arduino httpSecureClient -1 error at core 0 without reason why

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I'm having an issue with the httpsecureclient library for the ESP in the Arduino IDE.

I try to send http requests to a https domain (that doesn't change) and works alot of times just fine.

Like I do some HTTP calls to obtain certain data to let the ESP do it's thing. But when I want to let the ESP post a payload to a server, using the `WiFiClientSecure` and `HTTPClient`, it sometimes works without issues, but all of a sudden, it stops working and throws me the well known, nothing saying `-1` response code...

The code I ues to send a heartbeat is the following;

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

WiFiClientSecure ApiClient;
HTTPClient ApiHttpClient;


StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;
doc["mac"] = deviceMacAddress;
doc["key"] = DEVICE_SECRET;
doc["type"] = DIGITAL_HQ_SOFTWARE_TYPE;
String heartbeatData;
serializeJson(doc, heartbeatData);
ApiClient.setInsecure(); //skip verification of SSL cert
Serial.println("Sending Heartbeat");
ApiHttpClient.begin(ApiClient, DIGITAL_HQ_HEARTBEAT_ENDPOINT);
ApiHttpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
ApiHttpClient.setUserAgent(DIGITAL_HQ_USER_AGENT);
int responseCode = ApiHttpClient.POST(heartbeatData); // just post, Don't care about the response.
if (responseCode != 200) {
    failedApiCalls ++;
}
Serial.print("ResponseCode from heartbeat: ");
Serial.println(responseCode);
// Free resources
ApiHttpClient.end();
```

this code runs on core 0, via the following function;
`xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(sendHeartBeat, "Send Heartbeat", 20000, NULL, 25, &heartBeatTask, 0);`

I do call the heartbeat once in the main core, then it works, but then on the second core, it sometimes does, but other times, it doesnt.

There is nothing too fancy about this, I think and I really can't seem to figure this one out...

Side notes:

There is an MQTT connection running to the AWS IoT hub, on core 1, where I don't have any issues with.

Comment: I think some pages you're not allowed to visit without a certificate. Try setting a certificate and see if that works. Here is a nice guide: https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/11/18/esp32-arduino-https-get-request/

Comment: I don'yt think that should be the issue here. Since I do ´ApiClient.setInsecure();´ and that the requests work and all of a sudden they don't.

Comment: Well I'm just saying it couldn't hurt trying.

Comment: Tried with the certificates, same error....

Comment: Error -1 means that the connection was refused. So the response code does say something. Can you visit the URL you're trying to connect in your browser and see if the server is even online?

Comment: Yes, the URL is online (I own the domain and api it needs to connect to.)

Comment: Please read here: https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=9225. It says that wifi events are always dispatched to core 1. I'm no expert on ESP32 but I have an idea. Maybe the problem could be that tasks from both cores are trying to acces the single wifi chip at the same time resulting in core 1 getting priority and core 0 failing. You could try using a flag WIFI_IN_USE_CORE_1 and set it to true when core 1 is doing a request. Core 0 may only do a request when the flag's value is equal to 0. See if that works :)

Comment: There is a misunderstanding of what does `setInsecure()` do here. `setInsecure()` means that the client will not verify the server certificate, it doesn't means that you don't need to have a secure connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently run into same troubles after updating the libraries, old code for esp32 http clients stopped to work with the same symptoms.

I could solve this by switching to simply use HTTPClient only, without WiFiClientSecure. And it works with https.

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
    
void getPricesFromKraken(){
    String url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=DOGEUSD,XBTUSD";
    
    HTTPClient http;
    JSONVar data;
      
    http.begin(url.c_str());
    int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
    
    if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
        String payload = http.getString();
        data = JSON.parse(payload);
        Serial.println(data);
    }
    else {
        Serial.printf("http response code: %d\n", httpResponseCode);
    }
    http.end();
}
```